# Sum and uniform distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X_1 , X_2 , \ldots $ be iid
$P \left( X_i = 1 \right) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P \left( X_i = 0 \right) = \frac{1}{2}$ for $i=1,2, \ldots $

Let

$X= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{X_k}{2^k}$

Prove $X$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$

$\varphi_{X} (t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi_{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{X_k}{2^k}} (t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} E e^{i t \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{X_k}{2^k}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} E ( e^{i t \frac{X_1}{2}} e^{i t \frac{X_2}{2^2}} \ldots e^{i t \frac{X_n}{2^n}}) =  \lim_{n \to \infty} E ( e^{i t \frac{X_1}{2}}) E( e^{i t \frac{X_2}{2^2}}) \ldots E(e^{i t \frac{X_n}{2^n}}) =\lim_{n \to \infty}  \varphi_{X_1} (\frac{t}{2}) \varphi_{X_2} (\frac{t}{2^2}) \ldots  \varphi_{X_n} (\frac{t}{2^n}) =\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} e^{i \frac{t}{2}}) (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} e^{i \frac{t}{2^2}}) \ldots (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} e^{i \frac{t}{2^n}}) $

i don't now how do it

Comment: Hint: use the identity $$\tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{1}{2} e^{is}=\cos(s/2)e^{is/2},$$ for every $s=t/2^k$, concatenate the exponentials and use the identity $$2^N\sin(s/2^N)\prod_{k=1}^N\cos(s/2^k)=\sin(s).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $x=(x_0.x_1x_2\ldots)_2\in [0,1]$.

Prove that $P(X\le x)=x$, using base 2.